# Access mysql data base remotely from playframework 1.2.4

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to access sql database remotely from play framework version **1.2.4**

I am running play in virtualbox and I have mysql database in local pc.

**app/conf/application.conf**

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.47.78:3306/vedb

db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver

db.user=root

db.pass=aaa123aaa
```

**/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
bind-address=xxx.xxx.47.78
```

when I start the app with **http://localhost:9000/** I am getting below error

> A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, 
>   Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you define a mysql URL but set the driver to postgresql...
Try to comment the driver setting, or set it to: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

You can alos try to connect to your mysql server using the mysql command line:

mysql -h xxx.xxx.47.78 -u root -p

Then enter the root password (mysql root password). This will test the network connection to the mysql server.

Comment: hi,i am facing strange preoblem when i run "mysql -u root -p" ,i tried this but still same .http://askubuntu.com/questions/34095/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-error